Injectivity of a homomorphism between sheaf of meromorphic functions and sheaf of rational functions
I am reading the Gortz, Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry, p.303 and stuck at some statement.
First I arrange relavant definitions and lemma.

Definition 1. Let $X$ be a scheme. For  $U\subseteq X$ open we let $S_U$ be the subset of regular sections of $\Gamma(U , \mathcal{O}_X)$. This is a multiplicative subset of $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$. We define the sheaf $\mathcal{K}_X$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras as the sheaf associated to the presheaf
$$ \mathcal{K}'_X : U \mapsto S_U^{-1}\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X).$$
This sheaf is called the sheaf of meromorphic functions on $X$. Note that as every element $S_U$ is a non-zero-divisor of $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$, the homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{K}_X$ is injective. This allows us to identify $\mathcal{O}_X$ with a subsheaf of rings of $\mathcal{K}_X$.


Definition 2. For all open subset $U\subseteq X$, let $R(U)$ denotes the ring of rational functions on $U$ ( C.f. Gortz's book Definition 9.28 ) In the Gortz's book p.239, in remark under Definition 9.28, he notes that $R(X)=\varinjlim_{U}\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X),$ where $U$ runs through the directed set of open schematically dense ( scheme theoretically dense ) subschemes of $X$. Let $\mathcal{R}_X$ denotes the sheaf $U\mapsto R(U)$ on $X$.


Definition 3. Let $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{K}_X)$. Then let $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ be the set of $x\in X$ such that $f_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \subseteq \mathcal{K}_{X,x}$. It is called the domain of definition of $f$.

Then next lemma holds.

Lemma 11.23 ( Gortz's book ) For every $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{K}_X)$ its domain of definition $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is a schematically dense open subscheme of $X$.

Then in the book, p.303, the author wrote : For $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{K}_X)$ the restriction $f|_{\operatorname{dom}(f)}$ defines an element in $\Gamma(\operatorname{dom}(f),\mathcal{O}_X)$ and the lemma 11.23 shows that we obtain a rational function on $X$ ( Definition 9.28 ). For all open subsets $U\subseteq X$ we therefore have a homomorphism $\alpha_U : \Gamma(U,\mathcal{K}_X)\to R(U)=\varinjlim_{V}\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_X)$, where $V$ runs through the directed set of open schematically dense subschemes of $U$. I think that this map can be described explicitly by $\alpha_U(f):=[(\operatorname{dom}(f),f|_{\operatorname{dom}(f)})]$ ( Correct? ). And the $\alpha_U$ define a homomorphism
$$ \alpha : \mathcal{K}_X \to \mathcal{R}_X \tag{11.10.2} $$
of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras. As the canonical map $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_X)\to R(U)$ is injective for every schematically dense open subset $V$ of $U$ ( Why ?) , the homomorphism $\alpha$ is injective.
Q. Then my question is, Why $\alpha$ is injective ? Fix an ( affine ) open $U\subseteq X$. Assume that $\alpha_U(f)=\alpha_U(g)$. We want to show that $f=g$ in $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{K}_X)$. From $[(\operatorname{dom}(f), f|_{\operatorname{dom}(f)})] =: \alpha_U(f) = \alpha_U(g) := [(\operatorname{dom}(g), g|_{\operatorname{dom}(g)})] $ in $R(U) = \varinjlim_V \Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_X)$, there exists a schematically dense open $W\subseteq \operatorname{dom}(f) \cap \operatorname{dom}(g)$ such that $f|_W = g|_W$ in $\Gamma(W,\mathcal{O}_X)$. And at this point, I don't know how can we make any further progress. Can anyone help/hint ?
